GROMACS gmx energy LJ (SR) Calculation
I am looking at simple MD simulations of homogeneous Lennard-Jones (LJ) liquids to understand GROMACS’s parameters before moving onto more complex systems.
Currently, I am having an issue replicating GROMACS's gmx energy Lennard-Jones Short Range calculation (LJ (SR)). Could someone help me understand why based on the below discussion?
Method

Using gmx trjconv to generate .gro files of the coordinates of $n$ particles every 2 ns of the 22 ns run;
Reading the coordinates into Python and calculating the total LJ by:
Counting only unique pairs;
Additionally counting interactions between the $n$ system particles and the $26n$ particles in the adjacent periodic images;
Ignoring such pairs outside the cut-off
Subtracting the potential shift $V(r_\mathrm{cutoff})$

$n$ system particles in blue, $26n$ periodic image particles in red

#####system LJ
#pairwise distances and LJ potential between particles j and k,
#counting only unique pairs, including the cutoff and shift
for j in range(len(xs)):
   for k in range(j+1,len(xs)):
      r = np.sqrt( (xs[k]-xs[j])**2 + (ys[k]-ys[j])**2 + (zs[k]-zs[j])**2 )
      if r >= r_c:
         k += 1
      else: 
         LJ_system[i] += 4*eps*( (sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6 ) - shift
#####pbc LJ
#pairwise distances and LJ ptoential between j system particles and m pbc partilces,
#including the cutoff and shift
   for m in range(len(x_pbc[i])):
      r = np.sqrt( (x_pbc[i,m]-xs[j])**2 + (y_pbc[i,m]-ys[j])**2 + (z_pbc[i,m]-zs[j])**2 )
      if r >= r_c:
         k += 1
      else: 
         LJ_pbc[i] += 4*eps*( (sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6 ) - shift


i refers to the freeze frames
j refers to the system particles
k finds the uniquely paired system particles
m refers to the periodic image particles

Results


Blue points are my calculated LJ excluding the periodic images
Red points are my calculated LJ including the periodic images
The blue data is the GROMACS LJ (SR);

Questions

Am I accounting for the shift correctly in my Python code? Mathematically, I think I should be subtracting $V(r_\mathrm{cutoff})$ once off of the total LJ. However, this would be such a small number that I don't see how it wouldn't be negligible?
Are there any obvious issues with my Python code, particularly in the way I am accounting for periodic images?

Assuming there isn't anything else immediately incorrect about what I am doing, I am satisfied that the remaining difference is due to GROMACS's complexity, using Verlet buffer lists, etc.
Thanks!

+1. Welcome to our community.

Have you included minimum-image convention in your Python code -- calculating pair interactions based on the minimum distance between their periodic images, including across box boundaries or corners as necessary?

@ShernRenTee Thanks so much for suggesting that, I think that is the issue. I have updated the post to include this. If you have the time, it would be greatly appreciated if you could look at the two 'Questions' at the bottom of my post. I've updated the 'Method' section too for reference. Thanks again!
